# How can I make a link set a cookie for 1 hour with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
   <a href="/index.html" title="Click only if you are sure of your browser">
       I'm warned, <strong>let me in anyway</strong></a>
```

Is there a way that I can make the clicking of this link first set a cookie called 'forceAccess' to a value of 'yes' that expires in 1 day before it takes me to the index.html? I have the following function so I think I just need a way to call this from above:

```
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp PS: yes, I know w3schools is evil but it has the best explanation I could find in a short time.

Comment: Thanks.   I'm also confused as I can see how I could fire the script now but would it also go to the link as well ?

Comment: what if you check next time before ask? It really would take several seconds.

Comment: 1 hour in title and 1 day in question

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check for the cookie first and after that you can decide if you show the link or not.

The w3schools link in the previous comments can be of help but I also would like to advice you to use jQuery which assists you in manipulating the DOM in a cross-browser fashion.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if(getCookie("thisPersonIsSure") != true) { //getCookie is just pseudo-code
       var theLink = $("<a href=\"/index.html\" title=\"Click only if you are sure of your browser\">I'm warned, <strong>let me in anyway</strong></a>").click(function(){createCookie("thisPersonIsSure", true, 1);});          
       $(document.body).append(theLink);
   } else {
       //Go to the index.html immediately e.g. by doing this:
       window.location.href = "/index.html";
   }
});
```

Cheers!